# User registration Date of Birth field starts at 1930, how do I change that?

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

On user registration, the Date of Birth field starts only goes down as far as 1930. I want to allow older people to register as well, how do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can add a customer attribute from **Manage Customer Attributes** in backend for date of birth and save it as a text/date field.
Your attribute will be visible in the Customer details. 
Thats where you can save and get what ever age you want. Just keep the format same as magento date of birth for ease.